# Why does makensis.exe return errorlevel 1 even though it worked?

Tags: nsis, batch-file, errorlevel

I have a NSIS script that works.  It compiles, the produced installer works fine.  And yet, makensis.exe returns 1 instead of 0.  This is a real pain because I use it in a continuous integration setup and now my CI thinks the build failed.

This just started when I switched my project from SVN to Git, and made one tiny change in the NSIS script (I changed a path in two places).

- There are NO compile errors printed (even with /V4) that I can find.
- There are 6 warnings but they are the same 6 it had in the old repo where makensis returned 0.
- I diffed the previous, "errorlevel=0" output with the new "errorlevel=1" output and found no significant differences.
- It produces an installer that works fine.
- I'm still using the same exact copy of makensis.exe.

And yet, it returns errorlevel 1.

I am certain that I had this problem a couple years ago, but I can't remember how I solved it.  I think I just upgraded to the latest version of NSIS, but I can't do that this time (I'm already using the latest).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind.

The problem was in my batch file that executed makensis.exe.  It had something like this:

```
for %%A in (*.nsi) do (
    makensis.exe "%%A"
    if %errorlevel% neq 0
        echo %%A Failed.
    )
)
```

The problem is that %errorlevel% was being evaluated to a constant value at the beginning of the loop.  In order to actually check the errorlevel within the loop, you have to use `!errorlevel!` not `%errorlevel%`.  Also you have to have `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` at the top of your batch file (I had that already).

So evidently some prior unimportant step (possibly mkdiring a dir that already existed) was returning errorlevel 1 and then my check was thinking it was from the makensis call.  Of course this begs the eternal question: "how did this ever work?"

Comment: You could probably change that code to: makensis.exe "%%A"&& ( and skip the errorlevel if check